# Foundation: _userInfoForFileAndLine (Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException) [iOS]

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting this crash report from Crashlytics. Does anyone know why's this happening? Please help me. Thanks.

> Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException UICollectionView
> internal inconsistency: missing final attributes for cell
> <Cell_NAME: 0x1193123c0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell;
> frame = (0 716; 414 68.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x283944dc0>>; initial
> attributes: <UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x12640a2d0> index
> path: (<NSIndexPath: 0xac46dcd1e0749431> {length = 2, path = 3 - 0});
> frame = (0 716; 414 68.5); ; layout query:
> <UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x107239cb0> index path:
> (<NSIndexPath: 0xac46dcd1e0749431> {length = 2, path = 3 - 0}); frame
> = (0 590; 414 64); ; collection view: <UICollectionView: 0x109891000; frame = (0 0; 414 896); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers =
> <NSArray: 0x28369b3c0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x2838dff60>; contentOffset:
> {0, 244}; contentSize: {414, 1253}; adjustedContentInset: {48, 0, 34,
> 0}; layout: <UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout: 0x107398c10>;
> dataSource: <VC_NAME: 0x10e018600>>

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x990fc __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x15d64 objc_exception_throw
2  Foundation                     0x1303ac _userInfoForFileAndLine
3  UIKitCore                      0x227808 -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:]
4  UIKitCore                      0x17ae64 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews]
5  UIKitCore                      0x18d798 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
6  QuartzCore                     0x40138 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
7  QuartzCore                     0x32958 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
8  QuartzCore                     0x46f80 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*)
9  QuartzCore                     0x4f874 CA::Transaction::commit()
10 QuartzCore                     0x320b0 CA::Transaction::flush_as_runloop_observer(bool)
11 CoreFoundation                 0x41610 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
12 CoreFoundation                 0x108f4 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
13 CoreFoundation                 0xb98c __CFRunLoopRun
14 CoreFoundation                 0x1f468 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
15 GraphicsServices               0x138c GSEventRunModal
16 UIKitCore                      0x51a088 -[UIApplication _run]
17 UIKitCore                      0x298958 UIApplicationMain
18 DocTime                        0x5740 main + 20 (Model.swift:20)
19 ???                            0x10602daa4 (Missing)
```

Comment: it's for Model.swift line 20

Comment: Did you manage to learn context in which it happens? i e when user scrolls collection or when you reload it partially or completely. I have some crashes with such stack trace, and still can't find any common conditions.

Comment: @Varrry I haven't found the context either.